# EINVAL when initializing messages queue in constructor

Tags: c++, class, message-queue

I need to use message queues for a project at school. I wrote a wrapper, but `mq_open()` fails with `EINVAL` if I put it in the `constructor` (it works perfectly in the main...).

Here is the valgrind error:

```
==105030== Syscall param mq_open(attr->mq_maxmsg) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==105030==    at 0x4C9076D: mq_open@@GLIBC_2.34 (mq_open.c:51)
==105030==    by 0x10BEEC: MessageQueue::MessageQueue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (MessageQueue.cpp:13)
==105030==    by 0x10B308: main (main.cpp:9)
==105030==  Address 0x6c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==105030==
==105030== Syscall param mq_open(attr->mq_msgsize) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==105030==    at 0x4C9076D: mq_open@@GLIBC_2.34 (mq_open.c:51)
==105030==    by 0x10BEEC: MessageQueue::MessageQueue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (MessageQueue.cpp:13)
==105030==    by 0x10B308: main (main.cpp:9)
==105030==  Address 0x74 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Here is the problematic source code:

```cpp
// MessageQueue.hpp

#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <mqueue.h>

class MessageQueue {
    public:
        MessageQueue(const std::string &name);
        ~MessageQueue(void);

        bool is_open(void) const;

    protected:
        mqd_t _mq;
};

// MessageQueue.cpp

MessageQueue::MessageQueue(const std::string &name)
{
    std::string n = name;

    if (n[0] != '/') {
        n = "/" + name;
    }
    _mq = mq_open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
}

bool MessageQueue::is_open(void) const
{
    return _mq != -1;
}

MessageQueue::~MessageQueue(void)
{
    if (is_open()) {
        mq_close(_mq);
    }
}

// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "MessageQueue.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MessageQueue a("/abcd");

    std::cout << a.is_open() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "MessageQueue.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mqd_t _mq = mq_open("/abcd", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

    std::cout << (_mq != -1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I just found out that if I create a `MessageQueue` and then use `mq_open()`, it doesn't work either...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From [the `mq_open` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html): "If `O_CREAT` is specified in `oflag`, **then two additional arguments must be supplied**" (emphasis mine). If you don't provide those two extra arguments, their values will be *indeterminate* and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And *always* check for and handle errors in your code.

Comment: Not affecting this, but the constructor modifies `n` but still uses `name` in the mq call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, someone found it at my school.

It was in the `man` all along:

> If  O_CREAT  is  specified  in oflag, then two additional arguments must be supplied.

I don't know exactly why, but in the main, the arguments get a default values, not in the constructor. I believe there is a problem with scope (vtables... ?).

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with scope or vtables (which don't exist in C and `mq_open` is a C API). It is just undefined behavior to not supply the required arguments. No particular behavior can be expected.

Comment: Because this is a C API, not a C++ API, the two possible call signatures are not implemented as overloads (which C doesn't have) but as a single C variadic function. Therefore the compiler cannot tell you when you are missing an argument as it would usually do in C++. With C variadic functions that's just undefined behavior to forget one.